# Does class DSSP of biopython gives the relative solvent accessibility value of amino acids?

Tags: biopython, protein-database

I would like to have relative solvent accessibilities of amino acids in a protein, presently, using DSSP module of biopython. I am not sure if the output has rsa (relative solvent accessibility) or is it needed to be calculated? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, it does. It outputs a normalisation per residue type.
https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/DSSP.py line 44

It normalises followed Sander & Rost, (1994), Proteins, 20:216-226 instructions. The question is, is that enough for you? It might not be. 
Beware that biopython code does not allow RSA > 1, what makes sense, but I'd raise a warning rather than silently capping the number.

There are other aways of normalising it as well.